# deleted spark checkpoint directory and now it doesn't work

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I deleted the checkpoint directory for my spark stream.

Now, there are no errors, but the stream doesn't pick up any files.

How can I fix my stupid mistake? :)

I have tried to create a new checkpoint directory & changing the queryname but it's not helped

Below is the code that I have implemented.

I don't understand why it doesn't just make a new directory?

**CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#nohup spark-submit --master local --driver-memory 1g --executor-memory 1g streaming_log_monitor.py >streammon.log 2>stderr.log &
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as sqlfunc
import argparse, sys
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, input_file_name, lower
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
import sys
reload(sys)

sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

now = datetime.now()

#create a contexit that supports hive
def create_session(appname):
    spark_session = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName(appname)\
        .master('local')\
        .enableHiveSupport()\
        .getOrCreate()
    return spark_session

### START MAIN ###
if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark_session = create_session('streaming_monitor')
    ssc = StreamingContext(spark_session, 1)
    print('start')
    print(datetime.now())

    myschema = StructType([
      StructField('text', StringType())
    ])

    #only files after stream starts
    df = spark_session\
        .readStream\
        .option('newFilesOnly', 'true')\
        .option('header', 'true')\
        .schema(myschema)\
        .text('file:///home/keenek1/analytics/logs/')\
        .withColumn("FileName", input_file_name())

    def errorcapture(text):
      try:
        text = str(text).lower()
        if 'cannot obtain block length for locatedblock' in text:
          return 'error: Cannot obtain block length for LocatedBlock'
        elif 'outofmemoryerror' in text:
          return 'error: OutOfMemoryError'
        elif 'gc overhead limit exceeded' in text:
          return 'error: OutOfMemoryError (GC Overhead Limit Exceeded)'
        elif 'o3' in text:
          return 'error o3: an UnsupportedEncodingException occurred when setting up stdout and stderr streams.'
        elif 'o10' in text:
          return 'error o10: an uncaught exception occurred'
        elif 'o11' in text:
          return 'error o11: more than spark.yarn.scheduler.reporterThread.maxFailures executor failures occurred'
        elif 'o13' in text:
          return 'error o13: the program terminated before the user had initialized the spark context or if the spark context did not initialize before a timeout.'
        elif 'o14' in text:
          return 'error o14: This is declared as EXIT_SECURITY but never used'
        elif 'o15' in text:
          return 'error o15: a user class threw an exception'
        elif 'o16' in text:
          return 'error o16: the shutdown hook called before final status was reported.'
        elif 'o52' in text:
          return 'error o52: The default uncaught exception handler was reached, and the uncaught exception was an OutOfMemoryError'
        elif 'o53' in text:
          return 'error o53: DiskStore failed to create local temporary directory after many attempts (bad spark.local.dir?)'
        elif 'o54' in text:
          return 'error o54: ExternalBlockStore failed to initialize after many attempts'
        elif 'o55' in text:
          return 'error o55: ExternalBlockStore failed to create a local temporary directory after many attempts'
        elif 'o56' in text:
          return 'error o56: Executor is unable to send heartbeats to the driver more than "spark.executor.heartbeat.maxFailures" times.'
        elif 'array index out of bounds' in text:
          return 'error Array Index Out of Bounds'
        elif 'string index out of bounds' in text:
          return 'error Array Index Out of Bounds'
        elif 'error' in text:
          return 'Unidentified Error'
        else:
          return 'Success'
      except AttributeError:
        return text
      except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return text

    def errorsolution(text):
      try:
        text = str(text).lower()
        if 'cannot obtain block length for locatedblock' in text:
          return 'Find and resolve block issue'
        elif 'outofmemoryerror' in text:
          return 'Increase memory limit using --driver-memory 10g --executor-memory 10g in spark-submit'
        elif 'gc overhead limit exceeded' in text:
          return 'Increase memory limit using --driver-memory 10g --executor-memory 10g in spark-submit'
        elif 'total size of serialized results of' in text:
          return 'use this parameter in Spark-Submit --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=0'
        else:
          return 'Unknown Solution'
      except AttributeError:
        return text
      except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return text

    udfdict = udf(errorcapture, StringType())
    errorsolutionudf = udf(errorsolution, StringType())

    df = df.withColumn('did_it_error',udfdict(df.text))
    df = df.withColumn('solution',errorsolutionudf(df.text))

    from datetime import datetime
    now = datetime.now()

    output = df.createOrReplaceTempView('log')
    hive_dump = spark_session.sql("select '" + str(now) + "' as timestamp, FileName, did_it_error, solution, text from log")

    output = hive_dump\
    .writeStream\
    .format("csv")\
    .queryName('logsmonitor')\
    .option("checkpointLocation", "file:///home/keenek1/analytics/logs/chkpoint_dir")\
    .start('/user/hive/warehouse/design.db/streaming_log_monitor')\
    .awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your cluster has `trash` is enabled or not. If it enabled a file or directory is deleted that file or directory will be moved to the `.Trash` directory in the user’s home directory instead of being deleted.

Try using below path to check if your checkpoint directory is available or not.

```
hdfs://<host>/user/<username>/.Trash/Current/<your_checkpoint_path>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214468/discussion-on-answer-by-srinivas-deleted-spark-checkpoint-directory-and-now-it-d).